# problems installing matplotlib for Python -- or, how else to graph in Python?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-module

I currently have Python2.7, and Python3.3 installed on a Mac. I am trying to install matplotlib so that I can create candlestick, and line graphs. I have tried multiple methods of installing matplotlib, but they are all failing. For example:

```
port install py27-matplotlib
No broken files found.
MacBook$ python2.7
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

attempts at source builds off matplotlib-1.1.1 lead to C header errors.

The parent problem that I am trying to solve is to create candlestick, and line plots. Is there another library better suited to this maybe?

Comment: It is very simple to do with R. You can interface R from Python with Rpy: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Does `which python` give you the Python installed through MacPorts?

Comment: This isn't a problem with the library's capabilities, but rather of your installation of it (it wont even import!)... you should explain how you have attempted to install it.

Comment: "Use R" isn't really a useful answer. He's asking how to do plotting in Python.

Comment: Remove all traces of macports from your system and install [Python from Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python)

Comment: jterrace, That's not a very useful suggestion.  There's nothing inherently better about using Homebrew over MacPorts.  They both have their strengths and weaknesses.  The problem here is a simple one-time PATH problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you have a **python's path** issue and maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305154/python-will-not-recognize-macports-installed-packages) will be helpful.

update: i reemphasized my hint at the path issue because of a comment...

Comment: When you install third-party Python packages, like matplotlib, with MacPorts via a pynn-x port, they are installed into a MacPorts Python instance.  You need to use that Python; if you do, there is no need to set `PYTHONPATH`.  And there may be difficulties trying to force running of those installed packages with another Python (like an Apple-supplied system Python) as the build configuration of the two Pythons may be incompatible (architectures, deployment target, etc).

Comment: that may be valid objections, but i don't see how that warrants a downvote to a  1st most likely cause of his problem with 2nd link to an ACCEPTED answer and 3rd i DIDN'T propose a change to his PYTHONPATH - enviroment variable, but merely hinted the cause! btw. the linked answer does stress the point with the port supplied python version...

Comment: The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (as in the original answer) is totally different from the `PATH` environment variable.  So, yes, your edited answer is better.

Comment: Def pointed me towards the solution. Thanks.

The Unfun Cat, I had tried Rpy, and Rpy2, but found the number of graphing examples of the interface into R a little low. Are there some somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MacPorts-supplied Python 2.7, not the Apple-supplied system Python 2.7.  Try:

```
/opt/local/bin/python2.7
```

To avoid having to use absolute paths, make sure that the recommended MacPorts `bin` directories are on your shell `PATH` and run `sudo port select python python27` to select the MacPorts Python 2.7 as the default for `/opt/local/bin/python`.