# Trouble installing scipy with macports

Tags: python-2.7, installation, scipy, macports

I'm new to programming and trying to import scipy.

Problem:

When I try to import scipy in the python interpreter in terminal, it looks like this:

```
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
>>>
```

I seem to have installed macports correctly. I can successfully import numpy the same way as above.

I originally installed scipy as per "macports" instructions on http://www.scipy.org/install.html

ie:

```
sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose
```

Also I followed this post:
[Python will not recognize MacPorts installed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305154/python-will-not-recognize-macports-installed-packages)

but could not seem to derive an answer for myself

To clarify:

When I run "which python"
i get

```
/usr/bin/python
```

When I run "port contents py27-packagename"
I get

```
Port py27-packagename is not installed.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MacPorts does not touch the system python when installing python modules. It does install these modules for its own version of python, which is in `/opt/local/bin/python2.7` by default. You can make it the default python to be run when you type `python` in your shell using `sudo port select --set python python27`.