# ImportError: No module named scipy.linalg.blas on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to use decaf (`git clone https://github.com/UCB-ICSI-Vision-Group/decaf-release.git`) which depends on `scipy`, but I recieve an error:

```
slesarev-osx-2:decaf-release slesarev$ python build/lib/decaf/demos/demo_sparse_autoencoder.py
WARNING:root:Warning: I cannot import mpi4py. Using a dummpy single noded implementation instead. The program will run in single node mode even if you executed me with mpirun or mpiexec.

We STRONGLY recommend you to try to install mpi and mpi4py.

WARNING:root:mpi4py exception message is: No module named mpi4py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/lib/decaf/demos/demo_sparse_autoencoder.py", line 13, in <module>
    from decaf import base

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decaf/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import layers

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decaf/layers/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from core_layers import *

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decaf/layers/core_layers.py", line 16, in <module>
    from decaf.layers.convolution import ConvolutionLayer

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decaf/layers/convolution.py", line 5, in <module>
    from decaf.util import blasdot

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decaf/util/blasdot.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _numpy_blasdot

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decaf/util/_numpy_blasdot.py", line 5, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg.blas import fblas

ImportError: No module named scipy.linalg.blas
```

Comment: The warning says everything, you need to install `mpi4py` module.

Comment: We STRONGLY recommend you to try to install `mpi` and `mpi4py` ;)

Comment: I installed py27-mpi4py from mac ports, but the warning is the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that macports don't install packages for default python:
[Trouble installing scipy with macports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284696/trouble-installing-scipy-with-macports)